# Start Win32 process A which starts process B--get ID / HWND for B

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, process, win32-process

Okay, I spent a bit of time on this site figuring out how to start a "child" process (i.e., new process sets window parent to me) using Win32 calls from C#. It kinda works so long as it doesn't cross UAC boundaries. Fine.

Now I'm trying to do this with an uninstall program (process A) that bootstraps a temporary program (process B) which actually does the work. Process A goes away after creating B. My code requires a process ID from which to get an window handle which gets passed to SetParent. Looks something like this:

```
Process p = new Process();
try
{
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    if (p.Start())
    {
        p.WaitForInputIdle(10000);
        IntPtr pHwnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
        if (pHwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return null;
        }
        IntPtr currentHwnd = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
        if (SetParent(pHwnd, currentHwnd) == 0)
        {
            if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == 5) // access denied
            {
                // Need to launch privileged process that launches process 
                // and sets parent on UAC enabled OS.
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        // AND SO ON AND SO FORTH
```

Works great so long as p doesn't go away. In this case p goes boom after starting p'. Regardless, p never has a window handle.

So how do I monitor p to see if it starts p' and get the id (or more importantly the window handle) for p'? I can get the HWND from the id, but I need to get one or the other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be, check to see if p is null before trying to get its MainWindowHandle.  Here's some sample code which you can adapt if needed.

```
           using (Process proc = new Process())
            {

                proc.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ClientInstallPath;
                proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                proc.Start();

                if (proc != null)
                {
                    proc.WaitForExit();
                    returnCode = proc.ExitCode;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Oddly, WaitForInputIdle returns pretty quickly and p (proc) isn't null. So p.MainWindowHandle works with no NullPointerException. It just returns IntPtr.Zero. So I currently return null. What I need is a way to monitor p's process invocations and check it's new processes for window handles (assuming that p has none).

Comment: Note that in looking at your code, I'm pretty sure proc will never be null after teh call to Start(). I don't THINK the start method will dispose of the process object instance. Rather it'll throw an exception if it fails and/or set the HasExited and ExitCode props.

Comment: Could try and use SendMessageTimeout and see if the window responds to the message. If it doesn't response, you could assume its dead. [Check this link for details on SendMessageTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644952(v=vs.85).aspx) Any solution I think will involve the use of more WIN API calls in some fashion.